# Why do IR spectra of calculation and experiment differ?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, infrared-radiation, density-functional-theory

Recently I was simulating the IR spectra ( 400-3500 $cm^{-1}$ ) of an aromatic-like molecule with DFT. Then I did a comparison to the available experimental data.
Most data fitted well together: spectral lines are at (approximately) the same wavenumber and intensities matched in most cases. However, there were some differences:

- Some spectral lines which appeared in my calculation, did not appear in experimental data. Of course this is the case for small peaks because of line broadening. But there were peaks with very high intensity which did not appear in experiment.
- Some intensities did not match at all.

**My question is:**
What is the cause for some spectral lines appearing in calculation but not in experiment and why may the intensities of the lines differ by orders of magnitude? This should be a general question of what are the major causes of differences between simulation and experiment. The mentioned molecule is just a prototypical example i encountered.

**My attempt:**
When simulating a single molecule in DFT it’s like simulating a molecule in gas phase. However, most experiments (also the ones I found data from) are done by producing KBr pellets/discs. In this case the molecule is in a bulk and some vibrational modes (and therefore spectral lines) may be suppressed. If this is the case, is there some way of knowing which vibrational modes may be effected?